# Error during WebSocket handshake: 'Upgrade' header is missing (Apache 2.4 + mod_proxy_wstunnel)

Tags: javascript, node.js, apache, websocket

I have Apache 2.4 running on the server and have setup a subdomain to handle my Node.JS web app which also uses websockets.

My Apache site config for this is:

```
<VirtualHost *:80> 
  ProxyPreserveHost On
  ProxyRequests Off
  ServerName ws.mysite.io
  ProxyPass /ws/ ws://1.2.3.5:6789/
  ProxyPassReverse /ws/ ws://1.2.3.5:6789/
  ProxyPass / http://1.2.3.5:6789/
  ProxyPassReverse / http://1.2.3.5:6789/
</VirtualHost>
```

So that when users come to `http://ws.mysite.io/` - they get served the html from my node.js app (using express) and the html has a javascript part communicating back with the node.js app via websocket on `ws.mysite.io/ws/` which is "tunneled" to  `ws://1.2.3.5:6789/`.

I get a situation where on a home wifi - all works. No problems.

At work, we do have firewall, proxy... but i don't know exact limitations or blocks, but what happens is that when i open  `http://ws.mysite.io/` I get in Chrome console:

```
WebSocket connection to 'ws://ws.mysite.io/ws/' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: 'Upgrade' header is missing
```

Is this due to the work proxy "cutting" something off? Is there any chance to set up a "bullet-proof" tunnel to overcome things like that?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you don't need this line:

ProxyPassReverse /ws/ ws://1.2.3.5:6789/